# NodeJS service function is undefined

Tags: node.js, promise

I m totally a newbie in nodejs.Trying to read a json file in a service and then use it in an other service.
It tells me that my service is undefined. What am i doing wrong ?
thanks in advance !

JsonService

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
exports.getJobs = ()=> {
    fs.readFile('./common/data/jobs.json', (err, data) => {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (data) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And JobsService

```
const JsonService = require('../../common/services/json.service');



exports.list = () => {
    let jobs;
    JsonService.getJobs().then((data)=>{
       jobs = data;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(jobs){
                resolve(jobs);
            }else{
                reject(jobs)
            }
        });
   });


};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to read the json file, you could simply do

```
const jobs = require("./common/data/jobs.json");
```

Hope this helps.

The reason why your code is not working because you are trying to use it as a promise but getJobs doesn't return a promise. You need to wrap it in promise and then return. This is the way

```
const fs = require("fs");
exports.getJobs = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile("./common/data/jobs.json", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      if (data) {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

and use it like this

```
const JsonService = require("../../common/services/json.service");


exports.list = () => {
  let jobs;
  JsonService.getJobs().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

No need it wrap it in promise here.

But in your case simply requiring should work as I mentioned in above.